# Getting Error on Cloudflare Worker Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': the method is not implemented. at line 1 (Code: 10021)

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to import json data from web worker using importSctipts to make a worker for my website but getting this error again and again....i'm Using cloudflare is anybody here who can solve this problem.

Web worker code is here. **Need help...!**

```html
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');
if (workbox) {
workbox.core.skipWaiting();
workbox.core.clientsClaim();
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({
  prefix: 'thn-sw',
  suffix: 'v22',
  precache: 'install-time',
  runtime: 'run-time'
});

const FALLBACK_HTML_URL = '/offline.html';
const version = workbox.core.cacheNames.suffix;
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([{url: FALLBACK_HTML_URL, revision: null},{url: '/manifest.json', revision: null},{url: '/favicon.ico', revision: null}]);

workbox.routing.setDefaultHandler(new workbox.strategies.NetworkOnly());

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('.(?:css|js|png|gif|jpg|svg|ico)$'),
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'images-js-css-' + version,
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                maxEntries:200,
                purgeOnQuotaError: true
            })
        ],
    }),'GET'
);

workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({event}) => {
      switch (event.request.destination) {
        case 'document':
        return caches.match(FALLBACK_HTML_URL);
      break;
      default:
        return Response.error();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .keys()
      .then(keys => keys.filter(key => !key.endsWith(version)))
      .then(keys => Promise.all(keys.map(key => caches.delete(key))))
  );
});

}
else {
    console.log('Boo! Workbox didnt load ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to use an NPM module on a Cloudflare worker. Indeed, `importScripts` does not work, but you can use the static `import` syntax of JavaScript modules in order to load Workbox in your [Cloudflare worker](https://blog.cloudflare.com/workers-javascript-modules/).

You find here  the [the names of the different Workbox modules](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/modules/).
Here is how you would import the common core, precaching, routing or strategies Workbox modules

```
import * as precaching from 'workbox-precaching'; 
import * as routing from 'workbox-routing';
import * as strategies from 'workbox-strategies'; 
import * as workboxcore from 'workbox-core';
```

If you are writing your worker code locally and deploying it using [Wrangler](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/wrangler/), make sure you include `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file of your worker project.

Also make sure you have `npm install`ed all the `workbox-*` modules that you are using in your worker project